# What version of Crystal do I need?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting the following error after deploying my web application to a 2008 server...
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Crystal is not installed on the server but the .dll files are deployed.  It works on my local.  What file do I need to install on the server to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the merge module with you web application look in the GAC (C:\windows\assembly) to see which version of Crystal is installed then change the crystal reference tags in both your web.config and apsx files (bear in mind if it's a different version some features may not work)

Or if you have a spare license install 10.5 on the server using the server install utility:

https://websmp230.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm